# How can sed replace but skip the replaced characters in the pipeline?

Tags: awk, sed

I'm looking to escape some character `(` and `)`, their respective escape codes are `(40)` and `(41)`.

```
echo 'Hello (world)' | sed 's/(/(40)/g;s/)/(41)/g'
```

This code fails with `Hello (40(41)world(41)` because it will also process the output from the first replacement. Is there any way I can skip the replacement characters or do conditional branches here. I don't want to use a temporary (as the input sequence could contain anything).

Comment: replace with `[40]`, then have a final pass that replaces all `[` with `(`, etc. Good luck.

Comment: How embarrassing, why didn't I think of that?! I'm escaping [] anyways so it's a good solution.... Edit: No wait it doesn't work, because [] are escaped...

Comment: @shellter : You may consider posting an answer for this :D

Comment: @shelter that's a bad idea because it'll replace occurrences of `[` that weren't part of the previous replacement, e.g. it'd convert input like `a[b]` to `a(b]`. If you're going to use a temp character or string then you need to choose one that can't exist in the input, usually `\n` is good for sed given it's line-oriented nature. If that doesn't work because you're using the hold space (**don't!**) or need multiple temp values then doing `s/a/aA/g; s/<whatever>/aB/; ...; s/aA/a/g'` provides temp values `aB`, etc. for you by turning all original `a`s temporarily into `aA`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

```
$ echo 'Hello (world)' | sed 's/(/(40\n/g; s/)/(41)/g; s/\n/)/g'
Hello (40)world(41)
```

The above is safe because `\n` can't be present in the input since sed reads one line at a time. With some seds you might need to use a backslash followed by a literal newline or `$'\n'` instead of just `\n`.

Given [the answer you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37103168/1745001), though, this may be what you really want (uses GNU awk for [ord()](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Ord), multi-char `RS`, and `RT`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
@load "ordchr"
BEGIN { RS = "[][(){}]"; ORS="" }
{ print $0 ( RT=="" ? "" : "(" ord(RT) ")" ) }

$ echo 'Hello (world) foo [bar] other {stuff} etc.' | awk -f tst.awk
Hello (40)world(41) foo (91)bar(93) other (123)stuff(125) etc.
```

If you have an older gawk that doesn't support `@load` than get a new one but if that's impossible for some reason then just create an array of the values, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS = "[][(){}]"
    ORS = ""
    for (i=0;i<=255;i++) {
        char = sprintf("%c",i)
        map[char] = "(" i ")"
    }
}
{ print $0 ( RT=="" ? "" : map[RT] ) }

$ echo 'Hello (world) foo [bar] other {stuff} etc.' | awk -f tst.awk
Hello (40)world(41) foo (91)bar(93) other (123)stuff(125) etc.
```

**EDIT: timing data**

Given a file that has these 10 lines:

```
$ head -10 file1m
When (chapman) billies leave [the] street, And drouthy {neibors}, neibors, meet;
As market days are wearing late, And folk begin to [tak] the gate,
While (we) sit bousing {at} the nappy, An' getting [fou] and unco happy,
We think na on the [lang] Scots (miles), The mosses, {waters}, slaps and stiles,
That lie between us and our hame, Where sits our sulky, sullen dame,
Gathering her [brows] like gathering storm, (Nursing) her wrath to keep it warm.
This truth fand honest Tam o' Shanter,
As he frae Ayr ae night did canter:
(Auld Ayr, wham ne'er a town surpasses,
For honest men and bonie lasses).
```

repeating to a total of 1 million lines, 10.5 million characters, 60.4 million bytes:

```
$ wc file1m
 1000000 10500000 60400000 file1m
```

the 3rd-run timing stats for the sed script and both awk scripts above are:

```
$ time sed 's/(/(40\n/g; s/)/(41)/g; s/\n/)/g; s/\[/(91)/g; s/\]/(93)/g; s/{/(123)/g; s/}/(125)/g;' file1m > sed.out
real    0m7.488s
user    0m7.378s
sys     0m0.093s

$ cat function.awk
@load "ordchr"
BEGIN { RS = "[][(){}]"; ORS="" }
{ print $0 ( RT=="" ? "" : "(" ord(RT) ")" ) }

$ time awk -f function.awk file1m > awk_function.out
real    0m7.426s
user    0m7.269s
sys     0m0.155s

$ cat array.awk
BEGIN {
    RS = "[][(){}]"
    ORS = ""
    for (i=0;i<=255;i++) {
        char = sprintf("%c",i)
        map[char] = "(" i ")"
    }
}
{ print $0 ( RT=="" ? "" : map[RT] ) }

$ time awk -f array.awk file1m > awk_array.out
real    0m4.758s
user    0m4.648s
sys     0m0.092s
```

I verified that all 3 scripts produce the same, successfully modified output:

```
$ head -10 sed.out
When (40)chapman(41) billies leave (91)the(93) street, And drouthy (123)neibors(125), neibors, meet;
As market days are wearing late, And folk begin to (91)tak(93) the gate,
While (40)we(41) sit bousing (123)at(125) the nappy, An' getting (91)fou(93) and unco happy,
We think na on the (91)lang(93) Scots (40)miles(41), The mosses, (123)waters(125), slaps and stiles,
That lie between us and our hame, Where sits our sulky, sullen dame,
Gathering her (91)brows(93) like gathering storm, (40)Nursing(41) her wrath to keep it warm.
This truth fand honest Tam o' Shanter,
As he frae Ayr ae night did canter:
(40)Auld Ayr, wham ne'er a town surpasses,
For honest men and bonie lasses(41).
$ wc sed.out
 1000000 10500000 68800000 sed.out
$ diff sed.out awk_function.out
$ diff sed.out awk_array.out
$
```

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer your second piece of code over `sed 's/(/(40\n/g; s/)/(41)/g; s/\n/)/g; s/\[/(91)/g; s/\]/(93)/g; s/{/(123)/g; s/}/(125)/g;'`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't require you to know and hard code the ordinal values and you don't need to know which characters need to be escaped in a regexp and if you want to add more characters you just add them to list in the `RS` definition. It'll probably be faster than the sed script too since the sed script parses each line of input 7 times while the awk script does it just once.

Comment: Get a current version of gawk (4.1.something) but I updated my answer to include a solution if that;s impossible for some reason.

Comment: An attempt at disproving your speed hypothesis: I ran some tests of sed vs awk vs C. I tried making the test unbiased by running a warm-up round first. All programs read the same input: 1 GB of randomly generated bytes.
`C: 24.041 s, Sed: 31.277 s, Awk: 43.610 s`. These values seem a consistent trend. Also, gawk v4.1 does not seem available from the ubuntu repos.

Comment: Typically it's recommended to use the 3rd invocation for speed tests. Those speed numbers make no sense and seem utterly unbelievable anyway though. Makes me wonder about the scripts/programs you ran, the contents of the input file (you said "random" but not all "random"s are created equal), and whether or not the 3 programs produced identical output. Having said that, I don't care enough to investigate further. Sorry to hear you can't get gawk 4.1, its been around for literally years already.

Comment: The random was copied to pipes, so each program got the same input. If you ever care enough I'd like to see your results.

Comment: OK, timing data added. Needless to say I didn't write a C program to do it. So I guess the function call overhead of calling `ord()` plus the repeated string concatenation of `"(" ord(RT) ")"` slows that awk script down to the same as the sed script but the awk script that uses the array instead and only does the string concatenation once when populating the array is in the ballpark of about twice as fast as the other 2. This was GNU awk 4.1.3 in bash on cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by creating an ord function in awk. It doesn't appear sed has this functionality.

```
#! /bin/sh

awk '
    BEGIN    { _ord_init() }

    function _ord_init(low, high, i, t) {
        low = sprintf("%c", 7) # BEL is ascii 7
        if (low == "\a") {
            low = 0;
            high = 127;
        } else if (sprintf("%c", 128 + 7) == "\a") {
            low = 128;
            high = 255;
        } else {
            low = 0;
            high = 255;
        }
        for (i = low; i <= high; i++) {
            t = sprintf("%c", i);
            _ord_[t] = i;
        }
    }
    function ord(str, c) {
        c = substr(str, 1, 1)
        return _ord_[c]
    }

    // {
        split($0, array, "\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)|\\{|\\}", separators);
        len = length(array);
        seplen = length(separators);
        for (i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
            printf "%s(%s)", array[i], ord(separators[i]);
        }
        printf "%s", array[len];
    }
'
```

Comment: You're using gawk in your script (only gawk supports a 4th arg for split()) and gawk already has an ord() function, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37104339/1745001 for how to use it.

Comment: btw - the reason you need all those backslashes in your split command (`"\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)|\\{|\\}"`) is you're using a string in a regexp context (a [dynamic regexp](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps)). Unless you have a specific purpose in mind, use regexp delimiters (`/.../`) (a regexp constant) instead of string delimiters (`"..."`) anywhere you use regexps, e.g. `/\[|\]|\(|\)|\{|\}/`, to avoid that problem but in this case you should just be using a bracket expression anyway, i.e. `/[][(){}]/`. Also, `seplen = length(separators);` is doing nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky in `sed` but easy in any language with associative arrays.

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { %h = ("(" => "(40)", ")" => "(41)" ); 
        $r = join("|", map { quotemeta } keys %h); }
    s/($r)/$h{$1}/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in perl, which supports one-liners and look-behind in regular expressions. Simply require the close-paren not be part of an existing escape:

```
$ echo 'Hello (world)' | perl -pe 's/\(/(40)/g; s/(?<!\(40)\)/(41)/g'
Hello (40)world(41)
```

Comment: For a filter to not correctly handle its own output as input, that way lies madness.